# C# Custom Border Titlebar Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, api

I have created C# winforms with custom border and titlebar. I have disabled the controlbox `(ControlBox = false)` on the forum but it seems to also disable the system context menu that appears when you right click the titlebar. Is it possible to have the context menu while settings the controlbox to false?

Comment: Why would you want to disable it anyway?

Comment: I was just wandering if there was a way to do it. I want the menu without the caption buttons (min,max close). If there isn't I would have to handle WM_NCHITTEST on the right side corner of the titlebar, including HTRIGHT and HTTOPRIGHT. That's all, not to complex just thinking there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer as far as i know No

Long answer you cant use the context menu as it is part of the control box itself

Comment: Yep that's what I thought. I was trying to minimise the handling of WM_NCHITTEST.

Comment: I plan to mark it tomorrow. Just holding out a bit to see if there's another view. Gave you an Arrow Up for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

@System.Object has right, context menu is part of the control box, but if you really want to have it, you can write it your own, as I see the default titlebar context menu in windows7(restore, size,move,exit,etc..) is no big deal.

OR

You could rewrite your project in c# `WPF`, there is no much difference. And if you're planning more complex design, it should pay off in the long run.

Comment: A lot of the code is done in Winforms so it's a bit late to swap to WPF. Also I don't know much about WPF.